# How to login in to a page with GuzzleHTTP?

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I have a Symfony app that uses GuzzleHttp. I can't connect to my page using Guzzle. The application isn't on the same server/domain as the target website.

I don't have any error when I do a var_dump or an echo. It just gives me the login page.

Goutte\Client is a custom class to handle request. It was like that when I came to the project.

After a lot of tries it seems that the 'auth' property from Guzzle isn't working because I get the right login page but I didn't connect once.

```php
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

        $crawler  = $client->request('POST', "URL", [ 'auth' => ['user', 'pass'] ]);

        $crawler  = $client->request('GET', "URL");
```

And there is the Client class method who's called

```php
 protected function doRequest($request)
    {
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($request->getServer() as $key => $val) {
            $key = strtolower(str_replace('_', '-', $key));
            $contentHeaders = array('content-length' => true, 'content-md5' => true, 'content-type' => true);
            if (0 === strpos($key, 'http-')) {
                $headers[substr($key, 5)] = $val;
            }
            // CONTENT_* are not prefixed with HTTP_
            elseif (isset($contentHeaders[$key])) {
                $headers[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $body = null;
        if (!in_array($request->getMethod(), array('GET', 'HEAD'))) {
            if (null !== $request->getContent()) {
                $body = $request->getContent();
            } else {
                $body = $request->getParameters();
            }
        }

        $this->getClient()->setDefaultOption('auth', $this->auth);

        $requestOptions = array(
            'body' => $body,
            'cookies' => $this->getCookieJar()->allRawValues($request->getUri()),
            'allow_redirects' => false,
        );

        if (!empty($headers)) {
            $requestOptions['headers'] = $headers;
        }

        $guzzleRequest = $this->getClient()->createRequest(
            $request->getMethod(),
            $request->getUri(),
            $requestOptions
        );

        foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
            $guzzleRequest->setHeader($name, $value);
        }

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod() || 'PUT' == $request->getMethod()) {
            $this->addPostFiles($guzzleRequest, $request->getFiles());
        }

        // Let BrowserKit handle redirects
        try {
            $response = $this->getClient()->send($guzzleRequest);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            if (null === $response) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }

        return $this->createResponse($response);
    }
```

Methods that define 'auth' property

```php
    public function setAuth($user, $password = '', $type = 'basic')
    {
        $this->auth = array($user, $password, $type);

        return $this;
    }

    public function resetAuth()
    {
        $this->auth = null;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error message of some sort?

Comment: @SteeveDroz Hi I don't have any error when I do a var_dump or an echo it just gives me the login page

Answer (score 0):

This part here makes little sense, because `"URL"` does not appear to be a valid URL ...
also the previous result of `$client->request()` is being overwritten by the next one result.

```
 $crawler  = $client->request('POST', "URL", [ 'auth' => ['user', 'pass'] ]);
 $crawler  = $client->request('GET', "URL");
```

When emulating a browser-login, this may commonly follow this scheme:

```
// define base URL
$base_url = 'https://www.example.com/';

// first load the form
$result = $client->request('GET', $base_url . 'login');
// do something with result, eg. parse the form nonce.

// then post the form
$result = $client->request('POST', $base_url . 'login', [
    'auth' => ['insert username and', 'password here']
]);
// do something with result
```

Comment: I see exactly what you mean but I think I have to give you more informations, the application is aiming to get a list of people. So I can't see how I can login ( POST ) then do a file_get_content ( GET ) with one request.

Comment: @Gwen unless you'd configure the request with a valid URL & credentials, it won't request anything at all. Maybe use an IDE with Symphony support, alike PHPStorm? Xdebug is also quite essential for PHP. This is how it should look alike: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the Content-Type header as in some cases POST data won't be recognized by symfony w\o a valid content type. Perhaps, this is the problem. Would be good to look at the auth code on the server.